# mesh deform sideways when i copy and paste pose!

Tags: animation, rigging, dopesheet

I am trying to paste an animation, but everytime i crtl+c and paste ctrl+shift+v to the time i want, i get this weird distortion, i dont wanna correct it by hand because it will take a lot of time... and i dont wanna duplicate and invert by hand for the same reason, copy and paste should be working normally , i dont know why it is doing this distortion

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with your 2 tibias. First thing, recalculate their roll with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Global X Axis*:

[image]

Then rotate then -90° with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in order to align with the other ones:

[image]

It looks like you have similar problems for the arms. Also it's probably better to keyframe all the bones at frame 1.

Original pose:

[image]

Inverse pose:

[image]

Comment: In edit mode? Ctrl+N for 2.79 in edit mode. so i will have to do that for both tibia and arms and then clean all frames and remake? i realised that if i do this, all frames gets weird moves, did you see it in the file? so i better screenshot all poses before delete and then remake. if all bbones are aligned, i wont have the same paste problem again?

Comment: yes you may need to correct the animation, but at least from my try it seems to symmetrize the pose correctly once you've made these changes

Comment: in 2.7 it is Ctrl N to recalculate roll

Comment: lol for me it still didnt work, after recalculating the rolls and starting new anim, i made a text... it doeensnt get distorted but simply doesnt mirror x, he just lift his arms and shake the legs a bit lol urghh. its not that i am lazy, but copy and paste would make a much more smooth animation than trying everything by hand. i applied mirror already, location rotations , dont know what else can do

Comment: take a look at my edit, paste inverse seems to work fine once I've made the corrections, except you need to make some corrections as it is not the pose you want

Comment: mine didnt work, i did what you have done. i just didnt understand when you said to rotate manually... since i can recalculate both by pressing ctrl+N. after doing those steps it didnt reverse, just lifted the legs... this is so weird i feel unlucky lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133011/discussion-between-albert-paige-turner-and-moonboots).

Comment: after Ctrl N you need to align the orientation of the bone chain, to do so, Ctrl R -90°